# Creating an Expand All and Collapse All Buttons with Expander in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013, expander

I am working in Visual Studio 2013 in WPF (C#) and I have the following code to create an expander from my xml.  It is currently working perfectly right now but I want to include an expand all and collapse all buttons. I have looked all over and can't seem to find a solution.

Here is where the expander is created. I know I just have to iterate through a list of items and change the Property="IsExpanded" to Value="True" to create an expand all.

```
       <DataTemplate x:Key="dtListTemplate" >
            <StackPanel>
                <Expander LostFocus="CollapseExpander" ExpandDirection="Down" Width="Auto">
                    <Expander.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="Expander">
                            <Setter Property="IsExpanded" Value="False" />
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding XPath=@Name}" />
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>

                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsExpanded,RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="True">
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Expander.Style>
                    <ListBox Name="itemsList"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=UpgradeAction}"
                        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtListItemTemplate}"
                        SelectionChanged="listItems_SelectionChanged"
                        Style="{StaticResource styleListBoxUpgradeAction}"
                        ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource styleListBoxItemUpgradeAction}">
                    </ListBox>
                </Expander>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Here's the code that calls the DataTemplate which has information from an Xml.

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
            <Border Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Width="790" Height="40" Padding="5" Background="#4E87D4">
                <Label VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White">Test</Label>
            </Border>
            <Button Name="ExpandBttn" Width="100" Height="40" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Expand All" DataContext="{Binding}" Click="Expand_Button_Click"/>
            <Button Name="ColapseBttn" Width="100" Height="40" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" Content="Colapse All" DataContext="{Binding}" Click="Collapse_Button_Click"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <ListView Name="listItems" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Wheat"
             ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource xmldpUpgradeActions}, XPath=ActionGroup}"
             ItemTemplate="{StaticResource dtListTemplateRichards}"
             SelectionChanged="listItems_SelectionChanged">
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
```

Here's what I tried in the .cs file for the expand all portion.

```
  private void Expand_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
  {
      foreach(var item in listItems.Items)
      {
          var listBoxItem = listItems.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromItem(item) as ListBoxItem;
          var itemExpander = (Expander)GetExpander(listBoxItem);
          if (itemExpander != null)
              itemExpander.IsExpanded = true;
      }
  }

  private static DependencyObject GetExpander(DependencyObject container)
  {
      if (container is Expander) return container;

      for (var i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(container); i++)
      {
          var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(container, i);

          var result = GetExpander(child);
          if (result != null)
          {
              return result;
          }
      }

      return null;
  }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is `xmldpUpgradeActions` a CollectionViewSource?

Whatever class is in the collection, it should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Give it an `IsExpanded` property that raises `PropertyChanged` in its setter when its value changes, and bind that to `Expander.IsExpanded` in the template:

```
<Expander 
    IsExpanded="{Binding IsExpanded}"
    LostFocus="CollapseExpander" 
    ExpandDirection="Down" 
    Width="Auto">
```

Write a command that loops through all the items in the collection and sets `item.IsExpanded = false;` on each one.

Comment: Dang Ed you're rolling through questions on a mission lately, I can't keep up these days haha +1

Comment: @ChrisW. Very little sense of urgency at work at the moment, ha ha.